# Use the power series for $\arctan(x)$ to derive an expression for $\pi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, power-series

Given that the power series for $\arctan(x)$ is given by
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$ for $x\in [-1,1]$ how would you show that
$$\pi=2\sqrt3\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)3^n}?$$

I've tried by plugging in $x=1$ to get $$\frac{\pi}{4}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)}$$ but other then plugging in values I have no clue how to reach the conclusion

Comment: Why is there an $x$ in the equality you are trying to show?

Comment: Your equation $\pi = 2 \sqrt{3} \sum (-1)^n x^{2n + 1} / ((2n + 1)3^n)$ doesn't make sense, because the right hand side depends on $x$. Likewise, in your second series, $x = 1$ and you should not have $x^{2n + 1}$ anymore.

Comment: You still need to lose the $x$ in series number two.

Comment: Well, take $x=\frac1{\sqrt3}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\tan \frac {\pi}{6}  =\frac {1}{\sqrt 3}\\
\pi = 6\arctan \frac {1}{\sqrt 3}\\
\arctan x = \sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\\
\pi = 6\arctan \frac {1}{\sqrt 3} = 6\sum \frac {(-1)^n((\frac 13)^{\frac 12})^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\\
\pi = 6\frac {\sqrt 3}{3}\sum \frac {(-1)^n(\frac 13)^{n}}{2n+1}\\
\pi = 2\sqrt 3\sum \frac {(-1)^n}{3^n(2n+1)}\\
$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\tan^{-1}(x/\sqrt{3})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\dfrac{1}{2n+1}\left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^{2n+1}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)3^{n}},
\end{align*}
taking $x=1$, then 
\begin{align*}
\pi=\dfrac{6}{\sqrt{3}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)3^{n}}.
\end{align*}